# Unixtimestamp convert in date Y-m-d H:i:s PHP

Tags: php, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a date in Unixtimestamp (1100861208).
I am recovering it from an xml file and I have to write it in format (Y-m-d H: i: s) on the database.
How can I convert it?

i tried this way but it doesn't work:

```
$data_ins1 = $empl->data_ins; 
$data_agg1 = $empl->data_agg;
$data_ins = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime($data_ins1/1000));
$data_agg = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime($data_agg1/1000));
```

Do you know how to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert it just use the raw value

```
$data_ins1 = $empl->data_ins; 
$data_agg1 = $empl->data_agg;
$data_ins = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $data_ins1);
$data_agg = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $data_agg1);
```

or

```
$data_ins = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $data_ins1);
$data_agg = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $data_agg1);
```

If you are in the UK